# An uninitialized variable may have an undefined value, but does that undefined value have the same data type?

Tags: c, types

Say we declare in C:

```
int a;
```

Its value is undefined (let's forget those compilers that set zero by default). But does this undefined value still have the data type of the variable (integer)?

So it could be that `a=19382`, `a=23`, `a=-33332`... but not `a=33.2`?

This sounds pretty logic to me, but not sure.

Comment: The type of a variable is determined at compile time. An `int` is always an `int`.

Comment: In case of a float (IEEE 754 Type) it make a difference, since invalid combination of bits represents an invalid float. But for integers, it will be any (random) value.

Comment: @bkausbk it may also be a trap representation for any integral type (except `unsigned char`).

Answer (score 5):

As you have left it uninitialised, although `a` will consume the same amount of memory as an initialised `int`, the contents are indeterminate.

The compiler has to treat it as an `int`, so it could have any integer value. It can't be 33.2 because that isn't an `int`. It could however on some architectures happen to contain a 'trapping value' which would cause an error whenever you tried to access 'a'. Offhand, I can't think of any examples for an int, although floating point numbers do have values called 'signalling NANs' and some architectures will trap if you try load an invalid pointer into an address register.

Answer (score 4):

When it boils down to the bitwise representation of any variable, *only* by looking at that level, you cannot tell whether it is an `int`, `float` or whatever. That is why, the associated data type of a variable is required to understand and represent the type.

So, when a variable has indeterminate value, it is indeterminate. The point whether it is of the same type to the variable, does not make much sense, IMHO.

Just to make a point (*not strictly speaking*), you don't have any means to check the value of an uninitialized variable, as, trying to *use* (read) the value will generate [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: To elaborate on this: the type of a variable is really just "how do we interpret the bits in memory?". For example, a string of bits like 01000000001000000000000000000000 (hex: 0x40200000) interpreted as a 32-bit int would be 1075838976, while interpreting it as an IEEE-754 float would be 2.5.

Comment: The type still does matter, as you can do for example sizeof(a), which will be sizeof(int), not sizeof(something else).

Comment: @dbrank0 In that case of `sizeof`, I don't see how you use the _value_. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Sourav: This is valid, I think: int *a; a = malloc(sizeof(*a));

Comment: @dbrank0 Agree, but I still don't see how you use the _value_. FWIW, `sizeof` is a compile time operator, right?

Comment: You can not use the value. But you can rely on it being the correct type. In your last sentence you say, it does not matter (if I understood correctly).

Comment: @dbrank0 Well, to elaborate, it does not matter, actually. in case of `sizeof`, we are not bothered about the value, at all. Only need to know the type of the argument passed to `sizeof`, so the point of talking about the type of the value of the variable does not make much sense.

Comment: @SnildDolkow for an int, are they bytes stored in that order? Does Little Endian apply?

Comment: @BillWoodger on a little-endian architecture, the *integer* value 0x40200000 would be stored as 00 00 20 40 in memory. I don't think I've ever had a reason to think about endianness for floats, but Wikipedia had [some interesting insight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating-point_and_endianness).

Comment: An excerpt from that Wikipedia link: "Although the ubiquitous x86 processors of today use little-endian storage for all types of data (integer, floating point, BCD), there have been a few historical machines where floating point numbers were represented in big-endian form while integers were represented in little-endian form.[15] There are old ARM processors that have half little-endian, half big-endian floating point representation for double-precision numbers: both 32-bit words are stored in little-endian like integer registers, but the most significant one first."

Comment: @dbrank0 `sizeof(*a)` doesn't read the value because `sizeof()` **doesn't evalueate its operand** (except if it's a VLA).

Answer (score 2):

The value is undefined, so using it is undefined behaviour. It *could* be an `int`, but it's also possible to have a bit pattern that isn't a legal representation for any `int`.

In practice, it's unlikely to have bit patterns that aren't legal representations of `int`, but [c](/questions/tagged/c) doesn't guarantee you anything about it.

It can however *never* be a *different* type, because the type you give it determines how the bit pattern stored is to be interpreted.

Comment: That's not specified, but feel free to call [the C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.2.6.1) ridiculous.

Comment: Your comment is a bit pointless: the standard allows it, so an implementor *could* chose for example BCD as an integer representation. Discussing whether this liberty is "nuts" or not is out of scope here.

Comment: You're mislead here. The question is very generic, so just change it to a float type and you will have trap values on *many* implementations. What matters is the standard, not the fact that by chance, there usually aren't trap values for `int`.

Comment: You chose to mention `int` in your answer. Someone reading your answer may believe that their int could contain a value which would not be valid for an int. I believe that misleads, but you don't. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

If an ordinary int is declared outside of functions, it will be initialized to 0. That's guaranteed by the C standard, and if your compiler (in practice the runtime library that the compiler links it with) does not set it to zero, then it has a seroius bug.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf Section 6.7.9 paragraph 10.

If it's declared inside of a function, it'll have an indeterminate value, and accessing it might result in the dreaded undefined behavior.